# C++ shared_ptr passing to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers

I have following code:

```
struct Entity; // Simplified just for example  

struct BoxCollider
{
     std::shared_ptr<Entity> parentPtr;  

     BoxCollider(std::shared_ptr<Entity> parent) :
     parentPtr(parent)
     {}
};

struct MyObject : public Entity, public BoxCollider, std::enable_shared_from_this<MyObject>
{
     MyObject() :
     BoxCollider(this->shared_from_this())
     {}
}
```

And well, it doesn't work as expected - throws memory exceptions, `std::bad_weak_ptr`. How do I fix it?

I need that pointer is because the `Physics Engine` I use requires up-casted (`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`) `Entity` pointer; of which `BoxCollider` is derived from. Everything worked before I decided to move from raw pointers to smart ones.

Comment: Err..., you forgot to ask a question

Comment: Sorry, fix in sec

Comment: I've retracted my answer. The problem is that the even if you create your object with `std::make_shared<MyObject>` the `shared_ptr` hasn't finished initializing until well after the constructor of `MyObject` returns.

Comment: And I reply to that anwer: I tried to make it without it too like that: `BoxCollider(std::make_shared<MyObject>(*this)` (without star too) and doesn't work either.

Comment: @Condzi That fix would make things much worse. You would have a pointer to a *copy* of `this`, not `this`. Additionally, you would be creating a copy of an incomplete `this` (the constructor for `this` has only begun to execute). Is `parentPtr` only ever used as an alias to `this`? If it is, `shared_ptr` to `this` will result in an instance that will never be destroyed.

Comment: That's scary, maybe I should stay with raw pointers then. Can you write your reply simplier? I don't understand this sentence: `Is parentPtr only ever used as an alias to this?`

Comment: @Condzi You are using `BoxCollider` as a base class for `MyObject`. In `MyObject`'s constructor you try to pass a shared pointer to `this`. This means that in your example, `parentPtr` always points to `this`. Will this always be the case? If so, then using a raw pointer for `parentPtr` would be simpler and more correct. In general it is incorrect to store a `shared_ptr` referring the current instance as a member of your class. Instances of your class will never be destroyed because there will always exist at least one living `shared_ptr`, the `parentPtr` member. This is a circular reference.

Comment: You can't construct a BoxCollider without a parent.
You can't construct its parent without constructing a BoxCollider.

Comment: Thank you, how about `std::weak_ptr` instead raw?

Comment: @Condzi `std::weak_ptr` would fix the circular reference problem, but it won't work because it still needs a complete `std::shared_ptr` to construct from.

Comment: Is it one of rare reasons to use raw pointers?

Comment: @Condzi A generally safe rule of thumb is if you don't have to remember to call `delete` then using a raw pointer is not necessarily wrong. Remember that `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` represent *ownership*. While I can't be certain since you won't answer the question of rather or not `parentPtr` always refers to `this`, I suspect that you do not want `parentPtr` to be owning.

Comment: `parentPtr` always refers to `this`. Ok, I stay with raw pointers then, thanks for help.